# Is there a Linux package on Ubuntu that offers a sendmail tool which can forward the message with SMTP or fallback to a file when SMTP fails?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail, mail-transport-agent

I'm wondering whether there is a `sendmail` tool that would allow me to send emails without all the overhead we see in servers like Postfix. I use Postfix already, so I know how to set it up and all. But what I'm looking for is one simple `sendmail` command line tool to send emails from one server to the server running Postfix.

So... I'm running a cluster of machine in the cloud. One of those machines has Postfix installed and it works like a charm. I can send emails from any front end by saving the data in our system database and having a background task get that data and forward it to Postfix on that specific computer. So our software is taken care of, assuming the database is up, the mailer system backend is up, Postfix is up... when all of that is ready, emails start flowing as expected (we have two such installations and they both work just fine.)

Now... these cloud instances also run CRON tasks and some other subsystems that can end up sending an email (or at least attempt to do so.) By default that fails because no MTA is installed on those machines.

What I'm looking for is a way to have the ability to do:

```
prompt$ sendmail me@example.com
From: root@machine1.example.com
Subject: Problem Report

Here we go, the problem is that I don't want Postfix on  each machine.
.
```

Further, I'd like `sendmail` to be setup so if it can't connect to the computer running Postfix (maybe it's currently down) then the email message is not lost. Instead, it get saved in a file. For example, in `/var/mail/root`.

For sure, I don't want to have to run yet another server. I expect that `sendmail` tool to be a command line one runs when in need to send emails. That's all.

Anything like that available under Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be greatly overestimating "all the overhead" involved in running Postfix. It seems that would solve your problems: messages would get queued and delivered when your central mailer is back up.  That requires almost zero configuration in Postfix.

If you want something "simpler", there's [nullmailer](https://github.com/bruceg/nullmailer), but that still involves running a "server" to handle message queuing, so it's really just like postfix except you need to learn a new piece of software.

You could make your own using something like [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html#Changing-the-mode-of-operation), which doesn't handle message queuing or anything but you could wrap it in a shell script to saved messages to a mailbox on failure. Something like:

```
cat >> $tmpfile <<EOF
From: root@machine1.example.com
Subject: Problem Report

Here we go, the problem is that I don't want Postfix on  each machine.
EOF

if ! msmtp < $tmpfile; then
  echo "Send failed; saving to mbox."
  cat $tmpfile >> /path/to/mailbox
fi
```

You would probably want to add some locking to the above, or arrange
to deliver into a Maildir-format mailbox or something.

Comment: As a note, a local lock can easily be obtained using `flock /run/lock/sendmail.lock`